# C# Regex sorting letter and number strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list that needs ordering say:

```
R1-1
R1-11
R2-2
R1-2
```

this needs to be ordered:

```
R1-1
R1-2
R1-11
R2-2
```

Currently I am using the C# Regex.Replace method and adding a 0 before the occurance of single numbers at the end of a string with something like:

```
Regex.Replace(inString,@"([1-9]$)", @"0$2")
```

I'm sure there is a nicer way to do this which I just can't figure out. 
Does anyone have a nice way of sorting letter and number strings with regex?

---

I have used Greg's method below to complete this and just thought I should add the code I am using for completeness:

```
public static List<Rack> GetRacks(Guid aisleGUID)
    {
        log.Debug("Getting Racks with aisleId " + aisleGUID);
        List<Rack> result = dataContext.Racks.Where(
                               r => r.aisleGUID == aisleGUID).ToList();
        return result.OrderBy(r => r.rackName, new NaturalStringComparer()).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're after is natural sort order, like Windows Explorer does? If so then I wrote a blog entry a while back showing [how you can achieve this in a few lines of C#](http://gregbeech.com/blog/natural-sort-order-of-strings-and-files).

Note: I just checked and using the `NaturalStringComparer` in the linked entry does return the order you are looking for with the example strings.

Comment: Great answer Greg! I have now used this solution and will add the method i am using in my question for completeness.

Comment: Ya, great greg!  Too bad the LINK is DEAD

Comment: @Scott - sorry about that. I simplified the links on my blog and some of the redirects don't seem to be working properly. I've edited the post to have the updated link as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own comparator and use regular expressions to compare the number between "R" and "-" first, followed by the number after "-", if the first numbers are equal.

Sketch:

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    int releaseX = ...;
    int releaseY = ...;
    int revisionX = ...;
    int revisionY = ...;

    if (releaseX == releaseY)
    {
        return revisionX - revisionY;
    }
    else
    {
        return releaseX - releaseY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: Hmm.. Greg Beech's solution is nice! -- So take this as a way to solve it if you want to avoid the use of a DllImport.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have used Greg's solution but nice to have this for others reference.